# What keeps ports 32003 and 25419 open on my Ubuntu 14?

Tags: networking, exploit, ports

I did a netstat on udp ports and found a service on port 32003 and one at 25419. What are they , how can I kill them at startup if they have no use?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `netstat -nuptl` it will show you which process is bound to each port.